# Bad Substitution when I try to print a specific position of array

Tags: bash, sh

I'm getting started with bash programming, and I want to print a specific position of array, but when I try I get this error: Bad substitution

```
#!/bin/sh
user=`cut -d ";" -f1 $ultimocsv | sort -d | uniq -c` 
arr=$(echo $user | tr " " "\n")
a=5
echo "${arr[$a]}"   #Error:bad substitution
```

why?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: You are confusing between arrays and the command-substitution syntax`$(..)` for running commands and capturing and command output. The part `arr=$(echo $user | tr " " "\n")` does the latter and stores the output in a variable arr and not an array.

Also you are running with POSIX bourne shell sh as the she-bang(`#!/bin/sh`) interpreter set, which does not support arrays!. The `"${arr[$a]}"` is a representation to print an element from the index a on the array.

Comment: You need to run the script using the `bash` shell i.e as `bash <scriptname>` or set interpreter to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and run it as `./<scriptname>` in which case you could do

`arr=( $(echo $user | tr " " "\n") )`
which is not recommended though, as it undergoes word-splitting of the values present.

Comment: Arrays are more for storing multiple arguments to a single command than for implementing arbitrary containers. Much of what is considered good design in other languages doesn't really apply to shell programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "sh" which does not support arrays. Even if you would use the "bash" you get the same error, because the "arr" will not be an array. I am not sure, if the "-c" at "uniq" is what you wanted.

I assume, this is what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t arr < <( cut -d ";" -f1 $ultimocsv | sort -d | uniq )
a=5
echo "${arr[$a]}"
```

This will not give the error, even if your file has less than 5 unique lines, because bash will return an empty string for a defined but empty array.

It works even with "uniq -c", because it puts complete lines in the array.

Comment: You wouldn't get a bad-substitution error in bash. Array syntax can be used with non-arrays; you just don't get a meaningful value. `${nonarray[0]}` and `${nonarray}` are equivalent, and `${nonarray[i]}` expands to an empty string for any non-zero `i`.

Comment: But you can access a element using functions `function elem(){ echo $2; } ; elem array` will access second element.